# Why can't I use @Before annotation in my project? "Before cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to create a JUnit test class like this:

```java
public class AppTest {

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Create the application from the configuration
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( ApplicationConfig.class )
    // Look up the application service interface
    service = (TransferService) context.getBean(TransferService.class);
    }
}
```

The main problem is that I obtain an error on the `@Before` annotation on the `setUp()` method. It say to me that:

> Before cannot be resolved to a type

It seems as it can't find the dependency for the `@Before` annotation.

This is the dependency that I have in my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing? What is wrong? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You got the import statement? You know,  in the end any annotation is just a java class; so you need to things to make them work: 1) a jar/class file and 2) an import statement in your own code

Comment: try a ctrl+shift+O (windows) or cmd+shift+O (mac) to organize imports (on eclipse or STS)

Comment: I can't import this specific statment. It say to me to "create annotation Before", so it means that I have not into mu dependency

Comment: @ddb Be careful - not everybody is using eclipse. Or can you guarantee that your keystrokes organize imports for any IDE, editor?

Comment: I gave you the two things that have that need to be there. You figure which one gives you grieve ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Before` is available from junit 4.x, Change to newer Version of Junit.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall#beforeeach-and-beforeall):

> `@BeforeEach` and `@BeforeAll` are the JUnit 5 equivalents of `@Before` and `@BeforeClass`

So in case you're using JUnit 5, use `@BeforeEach` instead of `@Before`.